# Illustrating clustering in a figure

Tags: diagrams

I am currently writing an MSc thesis involving unsupervised learning/clustering. I am wishing to illustrate the basic concepts of clustering using a figure. The figure I wish to draw should look somewhat like this image from Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis#/media/File:KMeans-Gaussian-data.svg

How can I draw a similar figure in LaTeX?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This should be possible with `pgfplots`.

Comment: `pgfplots` can certainly do it. For a start, take a look at section **3.4.2 Scatter Plot Use–case B** in the manual for `pgfplots`. (Open a command prompt/terminal and write `texdoc pgfplots` to open the manual.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) provides a `normaldeviate` command that will give you Gaussian random numbers that you can add to a given coordinate.
Here's a way to use it to draw clusters.

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

% draw n random points centered on Z with r scattering 
vardef draw_cluster(expr Z, n, r, marker) = 
   for i=1 upto n:
      draw marker shifted Z shifted (r*normaldeviate, r*normaldeviate);
   endfor
enddef;

beginfig(1);

u = 1cm;
z1 = (2u, 6.4u);
z2 = (u, 4.2u);

picture mark[];
mark1 = image(draw fullcircle scaled 3 withcolor .67 blue);
mark2 = image(draw fullcircle scaled 3 withcolor .67 red);

randomseed := 1701;

draw_cluster(z1, 32, 0.8u, mark1);
draw_cluster(z2, 24, 0.3u, mark2);

endfig;
end.
```